# Why i'm i getting a Syntax Error in this Vagrantfile

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, syntax-error, vagrantfile

i just started to learn how to use Vagrant! So, as i'm trying to give my first steps in Vagrant I'm trying to create a vagrant environment using "vagrant up" but I'm getting a Syntax error on my Vagrantfile. Here's the Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

# Always use Vagrant's default insecure key
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
# Always use X11 Forwarding with r+this machine
  config.ssh.forward_x11 = true
# To avoid/allow install and uninstall of VBoxGuessAdditions.
  config.vbguest.auto_update = false
# Disable/enable automatic box update checking.
  config.vm.box_check_update = false



# Assign a friendly name for vagrant STATUS
  config.vm.define "mininet" do |mininet_config|
  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box.
  mininet_config.vm.box = "ktr/mininet"
  # Assign a friendly name to this host VM
  mininet_config.vm.hostname = "mininet"
  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  mininet_config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.11"
  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
    mininet_config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    # Change the VM name/ID in the Hypervisor
      vb.name = "mininet"
      opts = ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
      vb.customize opts
    end
  end

# Some shell provisioning when machine is launched
 config.vm.provision "shell", :inline "apt-get update --fix-missing"

end
```

Here's the warning from the terminal:

```
 syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_end
m.provision "shell", :inline "apt-get update --fix-missing"
                              ^
/home/alexandre/Desktop/3ano/RC/lab1/RC/mininet-updated/Vagrantfile:38: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me figuring this out.
Thanks for your time

Comment: You have a typo in your key value pair. It should be `inline:` and not `:inline`.

Comment: Thank you, it solve it! @MattSchuchard